# Authlib SSLError with self signed certs

Tags: python, ssl, oauth, authlib

I'm using authlib with the following code:

```py
session = OAuth2Session(client_id, client_secret)

token = session.fetch_access_token(
    access_token_url,
    client_id='.....',
    method='POST',
    client_secret=client_secret,
    authorization_response=request.url,
    code=request.args['code']
)
```

Which yelds a requests.exceptions.SSLError (CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED) when trying to access to my own OAuth2 server with self-signed certificates.

What should I do to use HTTPS regardless of this error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. pass `verify=False`, which won't validate the SSL
2. pass `cert="path to ssl client cert file (.pem)"

`OAuth2Session.fetch_access_token` accepts all parameters supported by requests. Check requests API documentation: https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.request

Comment: It worked for me using the flask client with MS graph and `resp = remote_app.get('me', verify=False)` as example get request. Is there a way to set the ssl cert for all requests made by the flask client?